# Решение квадратного уравнения (1 курс)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int function(double a, double b, double c)
{
   double &x1 = a;
   double &x2 = b;
   static int n;
   if (a == 0)
   {
       if (b == 0 && c != 0)
       {
           return n = 0;
       }
       else
       {
           if (b != 0)
           {
               return n = 1;
           }
           else
           {
               return n = -1;
           }
       }
   }
   else
   {
       double d = 0;
       d += b * b - 4 * a * c;
       if (d < 0)
       {
           return n = 0;
       }
       else
       {
           if (d == 0)
           {
               return n = 1;
           }
           else
           {
               return n = 2;
           }
       }
   }
  }

  int main()
  {
      int n;
      double a, b, c;
      cout << "Enter a, b, c: " << endl;
      cin >> a >> b >> c;   
      switch (function(a, b, c))
      {
      case 1:
          cout << 1;
          break;
      case 2:
          cout << 2;
          break;
      case 0:
          cout << 0;
          break;
      default: 
          cout << -1;
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

В чем смысл, нужно реализовать функцию, которая получает коэффициенты как аргументы функции(уже сделано) и возвращает корни уравнения, как аргументы-ссылки. Прочитал много инфы, но так и не понял, что и с чем едят эти ссылки.

Comment: `int function(double a, double b, double c, double& x1, double&x2)` — примерно это  от вас хотят...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример функции, которая складывает два числа и возвращает результат через ссылку:

```
void sum(int a, int b, int &c)
{
    c = a + b;
}
```

И пример вызова:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2, z;
    sum(x, y, z);
    std::cout << z << '\n';
}
```

Вам нужно сделать что-то похожее.